# Status of The Triangle Book

Tags: geometry, reference-request, triangles

I am interested in finding out about the current status of the planned book: The Triangle Book by John H. Conway and Steve Sigur. I understand that Steve Sigur died some time back. I got no reply from Prof. Conway; is there someone who knows the fate of this project. Is it abandoned or is it still under preparation? Here is some information about the planned [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568811659).

Comment: I'm still interested in this - any updates?

Answer (score 3):

The Triangle Book is on hold (Conway died this year) but there are people trying to revive it trust me.

Colm Mulcahy

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter is not acquainted with Colm. I trust him (except when he's holding a deck of cards). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colm_Mulcahy

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link, they say they want to publish the book in 2014:
http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781568811659

Answer (score 0):

Conway's 2015 biography Genius At Play by S. Roberts, a 2016 text [The Triangle](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.03379) by Richard Guy, and Conway himself in the first two minutes of his 2015 talk [How Turning Triangles Inside Out Helps Us Understand Their Geometry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1GhzHmjpDQ) say that The Triangle Book has not been written.

Answer (score -1):

On a little googling , i find that the book is for sale

[http://www.amazon.com/Triangle-Book-John-H-Conway/dp/1568811659](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568811659)

Comment: http://www.flipkart.com/triangle-book-john-conway-steve-book-1568811659

Comment: Neither of those sites actually has any copies available, though. I'm not familiar with flipkart, but I know that amazon sometimes offers books which are not yet released, not yet written, or even wholly invented.

Comment: When I follow the amazon link, one of the first things I see is "Sign up to be notified when this item becomes available."

Answer (score -1):

ISBN    9781568811659
Published   31 December 2004 by Taylor & Francis Inc
Author(s)   By Conway, John H.
By Sigur, Steve

Comment: There's no sign of it on the Taylor and Francis website, http://www.taylorandfrancis.com/books/ and there's no review at Math Reviews.

Answer (score -1):

Has anyone got any news? This is still available on pre-order.

When I contacted Book Depository at the end of last year, they apologised that its release date kept being pushed out, but all they could say was that it was still available for pre-order... i.e. no new information.

Is there anyone with more inside or recent knowledge?

Answer (score -1):

It might be assumed now that the book will almost surely never appear, both of the authors having passed away.